# How do I disable a link on double click but visit it with a single?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, hyperlink

Basically I want for the link to go ahead and run on a single click but on double I want for some other Javascript to run and not the link. I need something kinda like PHP's `die();` function.

HTML

```
<a id="link" href="'.$link.'">
   <div onclick="linktxt=this.innerHTML" ondblclick="show_msg_box()" class="more_item">' . $title . '</div>
 </a>
```

So somewhere in the double click, I need to disable the link.

## Answer

I just used `window.stop();` to stop the page loading ondblclick

```
<a id="link" href="'.$link.'">
   <div onclick="linktxt=this.innerHTML" ondblclick="window.stop(); show_msg_box();" class="more_item">' . $title . '</div>
 </a>
```

Thanks for the fast responses!

Comment: `ondblclick="show_msg_box(); return false;"`

Comment: Nope, still executes the link

Comment: Note that div inside a is not allowed in html4. Maybe that's what confuses your browser...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery try this:

```
show_msg_box(){
   this.preventDefault();
   //stuff to do
}
```

or directly:

```
<div onclick="linktxt=this.innerHTML" ondblclick="this.preventDefault();" class="more_item">'
```

Comment: Still executes the link. Is there a command to stop the page loading or something?

Comment: Thank you anyway:) Don't know why I didn't think of that earlier

Answer (score 0):

If you use underscore you can debounce the event handler: http://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery's dblclick event to run whatever you want on a double click action.

```
$('button').on('dblclick', handler)
```

or for flag method

http://jsfiddle.net/pjdicke/A6pUG/

```
var clicked = false;
$('button').on('click', function(){
    if (!clicked){

      alert('you can only click me once');
      clicked = true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="link" href="http://someurl.com">
    <div onclick="onSingleClick(); return false;" ondblclick="onDoubleClick(); return false;" class="more_item">ClickMe</div>
</a>

function onDoubleClick() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
    alert("DblClick!");
}

function onSingleClick() {
    if (!timer)
        timer = setTimeout(function() { alert('Single'); }, 500);
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zcRwu/)